# Existence of the limit $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{b^h-1}h$ without knowing $b^x$ is differentiable

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, education

When trying to derive, from first principles, the fact that exponential functions $a^x$ (where $a>1$ is real) are differentiable, we easily see that
$$
\lim_{h\to0} \frac{a^{x+h}-a^x}h = a^x \lim_{h\to0} \frac{a^h-1}h,
$$
*provided the latter limit exists*. It's even pretty easy to see that
$$
\lim_{h\to0} \frac{a^h-1}h = ( \log_b a ) \lim_{h\to0} \frac{b^h-1}h
$$
for any other real $b>1$, *provided the latter limit exists*. (And then one can define $e$ to be the number such that $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{e^h-1}h = 1$ and continue.)

So my question, which doesn't seem to have an answer on this site (though I'd be happy to be proved wrong) nor in the textbooks I've consulted: *how can one justify the existence of* any *limit of the form $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{b^h-1}h$ $(b>1)$, without using the as-yet-underived fact that $b^x$ is differentiable*? (Edited to add: I also want to avoid infinite series.)

Comment: This question seems like a paradox to me. $b^x$ is differentiable because the mentioned limit exists. That’s the definition of differentiability.

Comment: How do you define an exponential function? Do you use a series?

Comment: @RaiyanChowdhury I think OP is asking how to show that the limit exists.

Comment: @RaiyanChowdhury The exact derivative of $b^x$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, for every $b>1$, can be established if one can show that a single limit of the form $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{b^h-1}h$ exists at all. The latter task seems weaker in three different ways (just one $x$, just one $b$, just existence and not value). It's the latter task for which I'm seeking a proof.

Comment: @paulinho I want to avoid infinite series as well (I'll add that to the OP). So $a^x$ would be defined for integers in the usual recursive way, for rational numbers by inference (a la Cauchy's functional equation), and for real numbers as the supremum of $a^r$ over all $r<x$.

Comment: you can show the case where $b=e$ by using a substitution. if you let $h=ln(t+1)$.

Comment: Well, maybe Im not thinking about this right... but differentiation is defined in terms of limits.  If youre going to "assign" a limit a result by pure fiat, then you are effectively defining a derivative to the associated function and... asserting that a derivative exists by effectively defining one.

Comment: Seems like you should be able to prove, for small $x$, that for some constant $k, \vert b^x -1 \vert \lt k \vert x \vert$.

Comment: @SamaelManasseh That leads to $\lim_{t\to0} \frac t{\ln(t+1)}$, which seems similarly difficult without already knowing the derivative of $\ln x$.

Comment: @RobertShore Perhaps, but that's not sufficient, since it only shows the lim sup and lim inf lie between $-k$ and $k$.

Comment: @GregMartin Oh do we not know $ln(x)$ is differentiable and its derivative is $\frac{1}{x}$ by the FTOC ?

Comment: Provided that you prove that the function $x\mapsto a^x$ is convex (i.e. $a^{\frac{x+y}{2}}\leq \frac{1}{2}a^x +\frac{1}{2}a^y$ for any $x,y$, then the existence of the limit can be proven as in this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3806299/121671)

Comment: @OliverDiaz thanks, I'll take a look!

Comment: @SamaelManasseh There are various vays to formally introduce exponentials&logarithms, and starting by defining $\ln x$ as the antiderivative of $\frac1x$ is (in my opinion) probably the cleanest way to go ... but I'm teaching a course where differential calculus comes long before integral calculus, so I'm trying to start from that place.

Comment: @OliverDiaz So it seems to me that convexity (which I believe is easy to prove for exponentials from first principles) guarantees the existence of left- and right-hand derivatives; but I still don't see that it guarantees the derivative itself. (And I think there are examples like $|\tan x|$ where the derivative can be undefined). Am I missing something in this case? This is still the most promising lead I've seen.

Comment: @GregMartin: convexity will imply differentiability in an interval (with the exception of.a countable set). The isomorphism property of the exponential would then imply differntiability everywhere. I have to go  know, but if interested, I can post something later on this issue.

Comment: @GregMartin In my notes I define the logarithm as an area (the usual one) and “prove” the main property with an affine transformation that fixes the hyperbola and preserves areas. Once you accept this and the intuition that the logarithm is continuous, you can see that it is differentiable with squeezing. Therefore the exponential is differentiable as well, by the inverse function theorem. Defining $b^x=\exp(x\log b)$ one can show the standard properties that justify the exponential notation and apply the chain rule for the derivative. When you do integrals, you can make the proof rigorous.

Comment: @GregMartin: I made an edit and added an alternative methods, that it is perhaps more direct. It seems that it was a standard presentation in  Soviet textbooks in Calculus. It requires an introduction of the exponential and monotonicity and continuity properties; existence and tough estimation of $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(1+1/x)^x=e$. Then, by standard results (even in the west) the continuity and monotonicity of the inverse function (log) is established, and the desired limit results as a byproduct. I hope this helps.

Comment: @egreg Can you expound upon the hyperbola and area preservation bit? I suspect I know what you mean (but not actively), but maybe I don't and it's a great opportunity to learn something new.

Comment: @CameronWilliams You define $\log p$, for $p>1$, as the area under the hyperbola $xy=1$ from $1$ to $p$ (no integral calculus, just intuitive). In order to compute $\log(pq)$ one splits first into the area from $1$ to $p$ and then from $p$ to $pq$. If you consider the second trapezoid and use the transformation $x=pX,y=Y/p$, the hyperbola is transformed into $XY=1$ and the second trapezoid into the area from $1$ to $q$. The transformation easily preserves the area of rectangles. Then one can adjust for $0<p<1$, assigning negative area so the formula $\log(pq)=\log p+\log q$ holds generally.

Comment: @egreg Ah yep. I knew what you meant, just not as-phrased. I remember when I first saw that approach. It was quite enlightening.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Actually, I don't start from the trapezoid; the starting point is the “pseudotriangle” you get with vertices $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, $(p,1/p)$ (again $p>1$), with two segments and the arc of hyperbola as sides. This is an analog of the circular sector for the hyperbola; it can be easily shown that this pseudotriangle has the same area as the trapezoid and both give easy ways to approximate the value, by dividing the triangle or the trapezoid into smaller ones with geometric progressions. These approximations need nothing more than repeated square roots.

Comment: nice job with the pronoun edits. i got linked to this after i tried the same. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359106/are-pronoun-only-suggested-edits-acceptable and https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/924/is-it-acceptable-to-edit-a-post-just-to-change-the-pronouns

Answer (score 7):

This is just to address some comments by Greg Martin. I place it here for it is long for the comment section.

- Convexity alone will imply differentiability except on a countable exceptional set.

It is easy to check that convexity of a function $\phi$ is equivalent to any of the inequalities
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\varphi(u)-\varphi(x)}{u-x}\leq\frac{\varphi(y)-\varphi(x)}{y-x}\leq 
\frac{\varphi(y)-\varphi(u)}{y-u}\tag{1}\label{convex-equiv}
\end{align}
$$
For fixed  $a<x<b$, inequalities $\eqref{convex-equiv}$ show that the map
$u\mapsto \tfrac{\varphi(u)-\varphi(x)}{u-x}$
decreases as $u\searrow x$  and  increases as $u\nearrow x$. Consequently,
the maps
$$
\begin{align}
\alpha(x):=\sup_{a<u<x}\frac{\varphi(u)-\varphi(x)}{u-x}; \quad
\inf_{x<v<b}\frac{\varphi(v)-\varphi(x)}{v-x}:=\beta(x)\tag{2}\label{convex-derivative}
\end{align}
$$
satisfy
$$\begin{align}
\alpha(x)\leq\beta(x)\leq\alpha(y),\quad a<x<y<b\tag{3}\label{leftrightderivative}
\end{align}
$$

**Lemma:** The functions $\alpha$  and $\beta$ are monotone increasing and
left continuous and right continuous respectively.
Furthermore,  $\alpha(x+)=\beta(x)$ and
$\alpha(x)=\beta(x-)$.

Proof: Let $x\in(a,b)$ be fixed, and consider
the sequence $x_n=x+\tfrac{1}{n}$. From $\eqref{leftrightderivative}$,
it follows that
$\beta(x)\leq\alpha(x+\tfrac1n)\leq \beta(x+\tfrac1n)\leq n(\varphi(x+\tfrac2n)-\varphi(x+\tfrac1n))$.
Letting $n\nearrow\infty$, we obtain
$\beta(x)\leq\alpha(x+)\leq\beta(x+)\leq\beta(x)$. The corresponding
statement  for left limits follows by using  $x_n=x-\tfrac1n$
instead.

Since the functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$
are nondecreasing, we conclude  that, except for a countable set of
common discontinuities where jumps are equal,  $\alpha=\beta$ on $(a,b)$.

**Theorem:**
If $\varphi:(a,b)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ convex, then $\varphi$ is
continuous; moreover, $\varphi$ is   differentiable everywhere, except
on a countable set, and

\begin{aligned}
  \varphi(y)-\varphi(x)=\int^y_x\beta(t)\,dt=\int^y_x\alpha(t)\,dt
\end{aligned}
for all $a<x<y<b$.

Proof:
Suppose $a<x<y<b$ and let $x=x_0<\ldots<x_n=y$. Then
$$
\beta(x_{m-1})(x_m-x_{m-1})\leq\varphi(x_m)-\varphi(x_{m-1})
\leq \alpha(x_m)(x_m-x_{m-1})
$$
Adding all terms gives
$$
\sum^n_{m=1}\beta(x_{m-1})(x_m-x_{m-1})\leq\varphi(y)-\varphi(x)
\leq
\sum^n_{m=1}\alpha(x_m)(x_m-x_{m-1}).
$$
Consequently, $\varphi(y)-\varphi(x)=\int^y_x\beta(t)\,dt=\int^y_x\alpha(s)\,ds$; hence, $\varphi$ is continuous on any closed interval,  and differentiable everywhere except in the countable set $N$ of discontinuities of $\beta$.

**Comment 1:** There is no need to appeal to integral calculus to show continuity of $\phi$. I am sure the OP knows many ways to achieve this.

**Comment 2:**  Using the fact that the left and right derivatives $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are monotone along with the left-right continuity relations between them, one can conclude that $\phi$ is differentiable at every point with the exceptions of a countable set where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have jump discontinuities. All this, I believe, makes the arguments suitable for a course of differential calculus prior the introduction of Riemann integration.

---

- For the exponential function, if convexity can be proven, then differentiability at every point will follow immediately:

Suppose $\phi(x)=a^x$ is differentiable at $x_0$ (such $x_0$ exists from the discussion above. From the existence of
$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\phi(x_0+h)-\phi(x_0)}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\phi(x_0)\frac{\phi(h)-1)}{h}$, it follows the existence  of $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\phi(h)-1}{h}$. From this, the differentiable it’s at any point follows.

---

**Alternative method:**

I undust a couple of my old soviet textbooks (Kudriavtsev, L. D., Curso de Análisis Matemático, Vol 1, and Nilkosky, S. M., A Course of Mathematical Analysis, Vol. I) and this is more or less how the  derivative of exponential functions  are presented without the defining the log function as an integral:

1. Assuming that the exponential function $\phi_a(x)=a^x$ has been introduced and  continuity and strict monotonic properties are established (starting from exponential at rational numbers, exteding to irrational, etc)
2. The existence of  $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\big(1+h\big)^{1/h}=e$ and $2<e<3$ is established (starting from $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Big(1+\tfrac1n\Big)^n$ and then to $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}(1+h)^{1/h}$ using standard tricks)

then, for $a>1$

3. the $\log_a:(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ function, being the inverse of a strictly monotone increasing and continuous function $\phi_a$, is itself continuous and strictly monotone increasing.
4. $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\log_a(x+1)}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\log_a\Big(\big(1+x\big)^{1/x}\Big)=\log_ae$.
5. The punch line: To compute $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}$, let $t=e^h-1$ so that $h=\ln(t+1)$, $t>-1$. Then $h\rightarrow0$ is equivalent to $t\rightarrow0$. From this,
   $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{e^h-1}{h}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{t}{\ln(1+t)}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

If we allow ourselves to use the limit $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n = e,$$ we can subtract the constant inside the limit and use the [difference of powers formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_two_squares#Difference_of_two_nth_powers) to show that $e^{1/n} - \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) = o \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$:

\begin{align*}
0 &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left[e - \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n \right] \\
 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( e^{1/n} - \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) \right) & \left[ \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n-1}+e^{1/n}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n-2} + ... + e^{(n-1)/n} \right], \
\end{align*}

and clearly $\left( \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n-1}+e^{1/n}\left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n-2} + ... + e^{(n-1)/n} \right) \geq n,$ which implies $e^{1/n} - \left(1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) = o \left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$, or rearranging, $$e^{1/n} - 1 = \frac{1}{n} + o \left(\frac{1}{n} \right),$$ giving $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n(e^{1/n} - 1) = 1,$$ and changing variable to $h = 1/n$ we get $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{e^h - 1}{h} = 1.$$ We can use this right-hand limit to prove that $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{b^h - 1}{h} = \ln(b),$$ and in particular, taking $b = 1/e$ shows $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{e^{-h} - 1}{h} = -1,$$ which by taking $k = -h$ gives us the left-hand limit $$\lim_{k \to 0^-} \frac{e^{k} - 1}{-k} = -1,$$ or $$\lim_{k \to 0^-} \frac{e^{k} - 1}{k} = 1,$$ and we are done.

Comment: I guess technically we need something more in deducing the full limit $h\to0+$ from the subsequence limit $\frac1n\to0$. But your main point, I think, is that some sort of squeeze theorem argument should work here.

Comment: @greg You could do it with $x$ instead of $n$ and the argument works out basically the same way, although the difference of powers piece is a little messier when $n$ isn’t an integer.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned,we define the exponential function on $\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$ as $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^n\quad (*)$.

For $x>0$ and $n\in\Bbb N,$ the following holds:

$$1\le\underbrace{\frac{\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^n-1}x=\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^{n-1-k}}_{\text{difference of powers}}\le\frac1n\cdot n\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^{n-1}=\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^{n-1}\le\left(1+\frac{x}n\right)^n\tag 1$$

By letting $n\to+\infty$ in $(1)$, we obtain:
$$1\le\frac{f(x)-1}x\le f(x)\tag 2$$

For $x<0$,replacing $x$ by $-x$ in $(2)$ and dividing by $f(-x)>0,$ we obtain:

$$\frac1{f(-x)}\le\frac{\frac1{f(-x)}-1}x\le 1\tag 3$$

Now, from $(2)$ and $(3)$ and the definition $(*)$ of the exponential function,$\forall x\ne 0$, we have

$$0<\min\{1,e^x\}\le\frac{e^x-1}x\le\max\{1,e^x\}\tag 4$$

If $|x|<1,$ then $e^{|x|}<e$ and $\max\{1,e^x\}<e,$ so it follows that $$0<|e^x-1|\le e|x|$$ and squeezing we get $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}e^x=1$.
Now, let's write:

$$\min\{1,e^x\}=\frac{1+e^x-|1-e^x|}2\\\max\{1,e^x\}=\frac{1+e^x+|1-e^x|}2\tag 5$$
We see from $(5)$ that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\min\{1,e^x\}=1$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\max\{1,e^x\}=1$ and we apply the squeeze theorem to $(4)$.

And $b^h$ can be written as $e^{h\ln(b)},$ so we end up with the limit:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{b^h-1}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{e^{h\ln(b)}-1}{h\ln(b)}\ln(b)$$

Answer (score 0):

You could prove it using Riemann sums: Let's attempt to evaluate $$
\int_0^1 b^x dx
$$
as a Riemann sum. The curve is continuous and bounded, so there is a well-defined area under it which we can find using Riemann sums.

Split the interval up into subintervals of size $h$, and let $N=\lfloor \frac1h\rfloor$, i.e. we divide $[0,1]$ into $[0,h), [2h,3h), ... [N h, 1]$. The left Riemann sum is given by $$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} b^{nh} h + b^{Nh} (1-Nh)
$$
so we have that $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} b^{nh} h + b^{Nh} (1-Nh)$ is convergent. The sum is a geometric series, which we can simplify as $$
\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} b^{nh} h = h\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}(b^h)^n = h\left(\frac{b^{hN} - 1}{b^{h}-1}\right)
$$
Since $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} hN = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}h\lfloor \frac1h\rfloor$ converges to $1$,  we can conclude that $$
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} b^{nh} h + b^{Nh} (1-Nh) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} h\left(\frac{b^{hN} - 1}{b^{h}-1}\right) + 0 = (b-1)\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{h}{b^h - 1}
$$
converges. Thus either $\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{b^h-1}h$ converges, or it diverges to infinity, but diverging to infinity would mean $\int_0^1 b^x dx = 0$, which is false because $b^x > 0$ for all $x\in [0,1]$, so the integral must be strictly positive.

Comment: Fair enough, but if we wanted to allow integration techniques, then we might as well take the smoothest route and define $\ln x = \int_1^x \frac 1x\,dx$ right out of the gate; all the other properties of exponentials and logarithms follow from that.

Comment: It's true. But for what I have written, you don't need any integral properties other than the fact that they exist, so it is actually more elementary than the log definition.

Comment: Well, buried in the logic somewhere is the very broad fact that Riemann sums converge to areas in the first place....

Comment: Good point. I'll see if I can get a non-integral argument here; I think the geometric series is a promising approach though.